# Verticle Align Text with Three Div in a Row with Percentages

Tags: html, css

I have six DIVs. I would like three in a row. I am trying to make them "responsive/tablet" friendly and also easy mobile view. Each div will contain a glyphicon using span/icon How do you get the text vertically centered? How do you get the div to drop a line on a smaller device than a standard tablet size.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.one,.two, .three, .four, .five, .six{
   float: none;
}

.one{
    background-color:#323232;
}
.two{
    background-color:#2775EC;
}
.three{
    background-color:#800000;
}
.four{
    background-color:#00899f;
}
.five{
    background-color:#a500ac;
}
.six{
    background-color:#009000;
}

.one, .two, .three, .four, .five, .six{
    float:left;
    width:33.33%;padding-bottom:25%;
    border: #ffffff solid 4px;
    transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    z-index:0;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
}

.one:hover, .two:hover, .three:hover, .four:hover, .five:hover, .six:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 100;
    transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}}
```

```html
   <div class="container" style="width:100%">
   <div class="one"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="font-size:52px">One</span></div>
   <div class="two">here two</div>
   <div class="three">here three</div>
   <div class="four">here four</div>
   <div class="five">here five</div>
   <div class="six">here six</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit. For @media I want line after line meaning... I want the properties to stay just remove the float.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you indent your code properly. There are some syntax errors in your code. In your html you are missing a closing div tag for the container element. In your CSS your are not properly closing your media breakpoint.

I made some changes to your code, I hope this will help you.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">here two</div>
  <div class="three">here three</div>
  <div class="four">here four</div>
  <div class="five">here five</div>
  <div class="six">here six</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .one,
    .two,
    .three,
    .four,
    .five,
    .six {
      float: none;
    }
  }

  .one {
    background-color: #323232;
  }

  .two {
    background-color: #2775EC;
  }

  .three {
    background-color: #800000;
  }

  .four {
    background-color: #00899f;
  }

  .five {
    background-color: #a500ac;
  }

  .six {
    background-color: #009000;
  }

  .one,
  .two,
  .three,
  .four,
  .five,
  .six {
    float: left;
    width: 50vh;
    height: 50vh;
    line-height: 50vh;
    border: #ffffff solid 4px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .one:hover,
  .two:hover,
  .three:hover,
  .four:hover,
  .five:hover,
  .six:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  }
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/frankspin/pen/LkqXdL)

Comment: great thank you very much! i will test this out. I am teaching myself all this.

Comment: I tested this out. Works on a cell phone. Portrait divs go to their own line. Landscape you have three in each row.... great BUT ipads it goes Portrait div on each line (need it to be 3) and landscape goes to two divs on each line.